# pg_dump without postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a server with Postgresql. I don't have access to this server, just the endpoint to connect with psql. I want to backup data from this server to another server using pg_dump. However, my second server does not have postgresql and I don't have root privilege to install it either. 
Is there any way to run pg_dump without install postgresql?

It is possible to install postgresql on my client and pg_dump from it but I'm afraid the database is too big for my laptop.

Comment: if you install on your client you can still direct the dump save to a different server as long as you have write permissions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically we don't need any Postgresql server to take the backup. Postgresql client is enough for this.

But you must have sudo privilege to install this client.

## For Ubuntu:

```
echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
sudo apt-get install wget ca-certificates
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client
```

## For RedHat/CentOS/Amazon Linux:

Download the rpm here:
https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php#pg96

```
yum install postgresql
```

## Dump the Database

```
pg_dump -h remote_address -U username -D dbname -Fp > backup.sql
```

[image]

## More about Pg_dump:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgdump.html

Answer (score 2):

> It is possible to install postgresql on my client and pg_dump from it but I'm afraid the database is too big for my laptop.

Sure, `pg_dump` is just a program. You can download it or build it seperate from the others, also check out the -c option to `--format=format` if space is an issue

> `c` `custom` Output a custom-format archive suitable for input into pg_restore. Together with the directory output format, this is the most flexible output format in that it allows manual selection and reordering of archived items during restore. **This format is also compressed by default.**

Answer (score 2):

**For Windows**

Just download the version you need [here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries)

It is not necessary to extract all data from the archive, it takes up a lot of space.
It will be enough to unzip the `\pgsql\bin` directory, it will contain `pg_dump.exe`

To connect to a remote host use the `--host` parameter

Also, to simplify the work with pg_dump, I recommend adding the unzipped `bin` directory to the `PATH` environment variable. You can see how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to backup data from this server to another server ... my second server does not have postgresql ...

What are you hoping to *do* with the data once you get it onto the new machine?

Clearly, you're not *duplicating* the database, because you have no DBMS on the new machine to run it.  Therefore, a **backup** of the database will be of limited use to you.

I think you need to talk to those responsible for this database and get their take on the best to achieve what you need - whatever that might be.